# Закрепление окна поверх других в Qt

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

Как сделать, так чтобы окно всегда висело поверх других. Закрепить окно, чтоб оно никогда не переходило на задний план?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы виджет был поверх всех нужно использовать флаг [WindowStaysOnTopHint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

mw = QMainWindow()
mw.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
mw.setWindowTitle('Main')
mw.resize(250, 150)
mw.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо